# Adding multiple records (generated by faker js) into mongoose using node js

Tags: node.js, promise

I am very new to node and asynchronous programming. I am trying to add mutiple user object records (lets assume 5) into mongodb (using mongoose) using faker js for seeding my database.
I want to make this as generic as possible so that I can run the script explicitly to seed my database.
The problem I am facing (after trying and researching a lot) is my database process (be it create or save) is getting executed in asynchronous mode and by that time mongoose disconnect process is getting called as well.

Code snippet for User Data Loading js script:

```js
const User = require("../models/User");
const faker = require("faker");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const async = require("async");

module.exports = seedUser;

function seedUser(randomSeed, numData) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    faker.seed(randomSeed);
    console.log(randomSeed, numData);
    const userList = new Array(numData);
    // for (let i = 0; i < numData; i++) {
    //   resolvedUser[i] = await loadUser(i);
    //   console.log("I am outer " + resolvedUser[i]);
    //   await User.create(resolvedUser[i], (err, user) => {
    //     if (err) throw err;
    //     console.log("I am saved " + user);
    //   });
    // }

    async.forEachOfSeries(userList, (val, key, callback) => {
      console.log("Length " + userList.length);
      hashUser(key).then(resolvedUser => {
        if (resolvedUser) {
          console.log("I am resolved " + key + resolvedUser);
          userList[key] = resolvedUser;
          createUser(resolvedUser).then(data => console.log("Create " + data));
          // new User(resolvedUser)
          //   .save()
          //   .then(user => {
          //     userList.push(user);
          //     //val = user;
          //     console.log("I am saved " + user);
          //   })
          //   .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
      });

      console.log("I am outer " + key);
      // await User.create(resolvedUser, (err, user) => {
      //   if (err) throw err;
      //   console.log("I am saved " + user);
      //   userList.push(user);
      // });
    });
    console.log("whole list1 is " + userList);
    resolve(userList);
  });
}

function createUser(userObj) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const user = User.create(userObj).catch(err => console.log(err));
    resolve(user);
  });
}

function hashUser(i) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log("Loop number " + i);
    const newUser = new User({
      name: faker.name.findName(),
      email: faker.internet.email(),
      avatar: faker.internet.avatar(),
      password: "123456"
    });

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
      console.log(newUser.password);
      bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          throw err;
        }
        console.log(hash);
        newUser.password = hash;
        console.log("I AM " + newUser);
        // newUser
        //   .save()
        //   .then(user => {
        //     resolve(newUser);
        //     console.log("User Creation for " + user);
        //   })
        //   .catch(err => console.log(err));
        //console.log("I AM in resolve" + resolve);

        resolve(newUser);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

And I am calling this from wrapper js script as follows:

```js
const seedUserData = require("./User");
const seedAnotherUserData = require("./AnotherUser");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//DB Config
const db = require("../config/keys").mongoURI;

async function runProgram() {
  return new Promise(async resolve => {
    await mongoose
      .connect(db)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("MongoDB connected successfully");
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

    //app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server running on port ${port}`));
    await seedUserData(123, 5).then(list => {
      if (list) {
        console.log("List is" + list);
      }
    });
    //.then(list => console.log("Done " + list));
    //.then(() => mongoose.disconnect());
    console.log("Done ");
    console.log("MongoDB first save");

    await mongoose.disconnect();

    console.log("MongoDB Disconnected");

    resolve("Done");
  });
  //Connect to mongoDB

  //module.exports = seedUserData;
  //module.exports = seedAnotherUserData;
  //return "Completed";
}

runProgram().then(() => console.log("Completed"));
```

Would you kind enough to help me to overcome this. I know I am missing something, but can't figure out what.
Regards,
Sourish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few pointers on where the code might be tidied up :

- Promise constructor should be Function, not AsyncFunction.
- Throwing from synchronous code in a Promise constructor is OK (Promise will be rejected), but throwing from an asynchronous callback (ie from different event thread) is not OK (Promise will not be rejected).
- Always promisify at the lowest level; here that means promisifying `bcrypt.genSalt()` as `bcrypt.genSaltAsync()` and `bcrypt.hash()` as `bcrypt.hashAsync()`. Then `new Promise()` can disappear from the higher level code.
- There's far too much asnc/awaiting going on. Much of it is unnecessary.

Here's a reworked version using only `.then()` (no async/await):

```
// First promisify bcrypt.genSalt() and bcrypt.hash()
bcrypt.genSaltAsync = (n) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bcrypt.genSalt(n, (err, salt) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve(salt);
        });
    });
};
bcrypt.hashAsync = (password, salt) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bcrypt.hash(password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve(hash);
        });
    });
};
```

Then, with `new Promise()` looked after by those two promisifications, `seedUser()` becomes fairly trivial, even without `hashUser()` and `createUser()` as separate functions :

```
function seedUser(randomSeed, numData) {
    faker.seed(randomSeed);
    return Promise.all([...Array(numData)].map(() => {
        const newUser = new User({
            'name': faker.name.findName(),
            'email': faker.internet.email(),
            'avatar': faker.internet.avatar(),
            'password': '123456'
        });
        return bcrypt.genSaltAsync(10)
        .then(salt => bcryptAsync.hash(newUser.password, salt))
        .then(hash => {
            newUser.password = hash;
            return User.create(newUser);
        });
    }));
}
```

And your "wrapper script" will tidy up as follows :

```
function runProgram() {
    return mongoose.connect(db)
    .then(() => seedUserData(123, 5))
    .then(() => mongoose.disconnect());
}
runProgram()
.then(() => {
    console.log('Completed');
}, err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

**Notes**

- May not be 100% correct, mainly because I'm not familiar with `faker`, and I don't understand the double-shuffle with `User`.
- Assumes that all the `faker`/`bcrypt` stuff can be done in parallel. If not, revert to `async.forEachOfSeries()` (or similar).
- [...Array(numData)] simply creates an array of undefineds that can be mapped (a raw `Array(numData)` won't work). Alternatively, use a `for` loop to create the array of promises.
- `.then()` can be purged in favour of `async/await` though there's no particular advantage.

Answer (score 0):

I have now found the answer and thankfully my concept about async await and promises are now became more clear.

Modification made in the logic structure (in the asynchronous loop now I am inserting into DB) and usage of Promise.all.

Modified code snippets are as follows

```js
const User = require("../models/User");
const faker = require("faker");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const async = require("async");

module.exports = seedUser;

function seedUser(randomSeed, numData) {
  return new Promise(async resolve => {
    try {
      faker.seed(randomSeed);
      console.log(randomSeed, numData);
      const userList = new Array(numData);
      const resolvedUsers = new Array();
      const userData = new Array();
      console.log("type " + typeof resolvedUsers + resolvedUsers.length);
      await (async () => {
        await async.forEachOfSeries(userList, async (val, key, callback) => {
          console.log("Length " + userList.length);

          async function callback(resolvedUsers) {
            var resolvedUser = await hashUser(key);
            resolvedUsers.push(resolvedUser);
            var user = await createUser(resolvedUser);
            console.log("Create " + user);
            userData.push(user);
            return resolvedUsers;

            //
          }
          await callback(resolvedUsers).then(result => {
            console.log(
              "I am resolved " +
                key +
                result[key] +
                " and saved " +
                userData[key]
            );
            if (result.length === numData) {
              resolve(userData);
            }
          });
        });

        console.log(resolvedUsers);
      })().then(() => {
        console.log("see mee" + resolvedUsers.length);
      });

      // resolvePromise
      //   .then(() => {
      //     Promise.all(
      //       resolvedUsers.map(resolvedUser => {
      //         console.log("Inside all " + resolvedUser);
      //         createUser(resolvedUser).then(user => {
      //           console.log("Create " + user);
      //           userData.push(user);
      //         });
      //       })
      //     );
      //   })
      //   .then(() => {
      //     console.log("whole list1 is " + userData);
      //     resolve(userData);
      //   });

      //console.log(next);

      //await Promise.all([resolvePromise(), next()]);
      //    userData[key] = createUser(resolvedUser[key]);

      //userList[key] = resolvedUser[key];

      //console.log("I am outer " + key);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}

function createUser(userObj) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const user = User.create(userObj).catch(err => console.log(err));
    resolve(user);
  });
}

function hashUser(i) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log("Loop number " + i);
    const newUser = new User({
      name: faker.name.findName(),
      email: faker.internet.email(),
      avatar: faker.internet.avatar(),
      password: "123456"
    });

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
      console.log(newUser.password);
      bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          throw err;
        }
        console.log(hash);
        newUser.password = hash;
        console.log("I AM " + newUser);
        // newUser
        //   .save()
        //   .then(user => {
        //     resolve(newUser);
        //     console.log("User Creation for " + user);
        //   })
        //   .catch(err => console.log(err));
        //console.log("I AM in resolve" + resolve);
        resolve(newUser);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

And the wrapper is as follows:

```js
const seedUserData = require("./User");
const seedAnotherUserData = require("./AnotherUser");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//DB Config
const db = require("../config/keys").mongoURI;

async function runProgram() {
  //  return new Promise(async resolve => {
  try {
    const conObj = mongoose.connect(db);
    if (conObj) {
      console.log("Mongo successfully connected" + conObj);
    }

    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

    const userList = await seedUserData(23456, 50);

    if (userList) {
      console.log("List is" + userList);
    }

    //await Promise.all([conObj, userList]);

    console.log("Done ");
    console.log("MongoDB first save");

    await mongoose.disconnect();

    console.log("MongoDB Disconnected");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  // //app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server running on port ${port}`));
  // await seedUserData(123, 5).then(list => {
  //   if (list) {
  //     console.log("List is" + list);
  //   }
  // });
  //.then(list => console.log("Done " + list));
  //.then(() => mongoose.disconnect());

  //   resolve("Done");
  // });
  //Connect to mongoDB

  //module.exports = seedUserData;
  //module.exports = seedAnotherUserData;
  //return "Completed";
}

runProgram().then(() => console.log("Completed"));
```

Regards,
Sourish

Comment: This may kind of work but there's a whole lot of nonsense in there. It still needs a lot of work. The eventual code should be reasonably compact.

Comment: Sure.. I understand. Appreciate your advise. I am very new in this technology and trying to learn as hard as possible..

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should work in general, but you have a lot of unnecessary syntax and your code could be a lot cleaner. For example, there's no reason to ever do `await (async () => { await fn(); })`, just do `await fn();` . Also, there's no reason to use `async.forEachOfSeries()` with async/await, you can just use a plain old `for` loop. Here's some more [examples of using async/await with Mongoose](http://thecodebarbarian.com/using-async-await-with-mocha-express-and-mongoose#mongoose).